# Serverless framework can't connect to existing REST API in AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless, serverless-framework

Hello and thanks in advance for the help,
Im trying to connect my serverless file to an existing API Rest in AWS but when I make the deploy it fails with the message:
CREATE_FAILED: ApiGatewayResourceOtherversion (AWS::ApiGateway::Resource)
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid Resource identifier specified

Here is the configuration in my serverless file and the API in the cloud

```
service: test-api-2

frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  region: us-east-1
  runtime: python3.8
  apiGateway: 
    restApiId: 7o3h7b2zy5
    restApiRootResourceId: "/second"



functions:
  hello_oscar:
    handler: test-api/handler.hello_oscar
    events:
        # every Monday at 03:15 AM
        - schedule: cron(15 3 ? * MON *)
        #- sqs: arn:aws:sqs:region:XXXXXX:MyFirstQueue
    package:
      include:
        - test-api/**
  get:
    handler:  hexa/application/get/get.get_information
    memorySize: 128
    description: Test function
    events:
    - http:
        path: /hola
        method: GET
        cors: true
    package:
      include:
        - hexa/**
  other_version:
    handler: other_version/use_other.another_version
    layers:
      - xxxxxxxxx
    runtime: python3.7
    description: Uses other version of python3.7
    events:
      - http:
          path: /other_version
          method: POST
          cors: true
    package:
      include:
        - other_version/**
  diferente:
    handler: other_version/use_other.another_version
    layers:
      - xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    runtime: python3.8
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the example serverless.yml, where you have the `restApiRootResourceId` property set to `/second`, you should have it set to the root resource id, which is shown in your screen shot as `bt6nd8xw4l`